# What lens should we use to shoot large products in a small studio?

Tags: lens, canon, product-photography, studio, lens-recommendation

I work for a company that sells events and trade show booths. We have a studio to shoot the products, but unfortunately, it is on the small side. I would need a wide angle lens to shoot the products. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Additional info:

- Camera is a Canon SLR; need a Canon EF compatible lens.
- Products are very large — typically footprint is 10ft wide × 8ft high.
- Photo space is 20 ft wide × 20 ft.

Comment: Is it a full frame or an crop sensor SLR camera?

Comment: Are the products just flat, like posters?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [this online calculator](http://www.supercircuits.com/resources/tools/fov-calculator) to calculate an appropriate lens in your situation.

For example, using the calculator, I can see that (on a full-frame/35" sensor) you'll probably need a lens that has a 20" equivalent focal length or less:

[image: focal length calculator]

To get this result I popped 20 feet in the *distance* input, and guessed at around 20mm for the focal length input. I left the width and height blank.

You may want to bring the distance down, to account for the photography equipment in the room. You may also want to use the radio buttons to change the sensor size, depending on your Canon model.

Comment: Inches or millimeters? The diagonal of a 35mm FF camera is about 43mm, considerably larger than a 1" sensor which has a diagonal of around 16mm. The term 1" goes back to the way image sizes of video cameras used until the late 1980s were expressed, referring to the outside diameter of the glass envelope of the video camera tube.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like a Canon 24-70L F/2.8
or if your on a budget, maybe a old 35mm M42 prime lens with a M42 to EOS adapter.
The sharpest lens Iv'e used for film making was a Zenit/Helios 58mm F2 and they normally cost around £10 GBP.

Comment: Can ou provide insight about your recommendation ? As it is, your answer isn't very helpful.